# What are the differences between a real user action and a programmatically generated?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

I'm working with webkit notifications on Chrome.
The method `window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission` can only be called from a user action (click, etc.). Call it anywhere else will have no effect and will not throw any error.

For some reasons I need to run it later on another event, originally generated by a real click.

I tried to run this method by generating a click like this:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.addEventListener('click', function () {
  window.webkitNotifications.requestPermission()
});
var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
false, false, false, false, 0, null);
a.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

But as expected the method has no effect.
Which leads me to wonder how Chrome really detects user actions? 
What's the difference between a generated event and one generated by a real user action?

I've also tried to keep a reference to the original click event and pass it back when I need to call this method, but it does not work.

I've created a fiddle to illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/arnaudbreton/B38yJ/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All click actions generated by user will have a secret property that indicates whether the event was created by user or not. It is not visible to developers, but is there for the underlying javascript engine.

It is necessary in order to prevent malicious codes from running on user's browser, for example when you visit a malicious website by accident.

One common example is that you cannot open a file browser dialog by simply triggering a click event on `input[type=file]`. User has create a true click event to open a file browser.

Another thing is that all event listeners must be synchronous to trigger security-sensitive functions like your example above.

In conclusion, fake events cannot call security-sensitive browser APIs.